# What am I supposed to do in a random event?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

So far I've encountered two random events while driving around Los Santos. Both involved a street robbery.

What am I supposed to do here? So far I've tried chasing the perps down on foot (and couldn't even get close) and running them over with my car. In one case, I hit the guy hard enough that I knocked him off an overpass... and then he got up and kept running.

I sort of tried shooting them too, but they were too far away and my aim is terrible.

So, how can I resolve these events?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this type of random events you have to chase the robber and get back the stolen item(which is just a wallet in most of the cases). As you said, you should just chase them on a car and run him over. If he didn't drop a wallet(the dot on the radar is still red, pointing on the guy), pull back a few meters and drive him over again. Repeat until he drops the wallet.

You could also step out of your car(after you knocked him down the first time) and beat/shoot him. I once had a robber that dropped a wallet after he heard/felt some gunshots screaming something like *Ok, ok, whatever, take it!*

If the robber is using a bike/car, try chasing him and shooting. Aim for the robber(fairly difficult) or for the wheels(easier). If you manage to pop the wheel(s), the car will stop and the robber will most probably get out and try to shoot you.

Once you get the wallet your balance will go up(I've had amounts between $200 and $2000). Then you have a choice whether to give the wallet/item back to the victim or keep it. The first time I encountered such an event, I got a tooltip saying that I can return it for some money(which is obviously less than was in the wallet) and get a chance to increase one of the stats or get some other bonus. Or I could just keep the wallet to myself. I've always been returning it and never got any non-monetary bonus yet. The victims thank you by taking only 90% of found sum.

So, for example if you got a wallet with $500 in it and you return it, the citizen will take $450 of it(returning $50 of the $500 to you as a thank). The ratio is always the same.

And what I did as well: right after returning the money to the victim I shot him/her and got the remaining sum(or maybe a little more) back.

So for these events I'd return everything hoping for some reward and then just kill the person and get the money back.

There are also other random events, I don't know them all, I only encountered robbery and car hijacking. However I wasn't able to keep up with the bad guy and he drove away(back then I was playing as Trevor with only like 30% driving skill).

Comment: I find your methodology very disturbing. "Hey, I'm a nice guy for returning your money! Here you go!" **BLAM** "Thanks for the cash."

Comment: It's GTA, what do you expect @Sterno?

Comment: Some of the non-monetary bonuses you get later on. The mission was retrieving a stolen bike, and you an e-mail an in-game day or so later.

Answer (score 6):

Well, that is pretty much exactly what you have to do (in this particular random event): Stop (kill) the robber.

If you successfully stop the robber, he will drop the money he stole (it's marked on your minimap). You can then decide if you want to keep it, or give it back.